# How to test a function in jest that throws an error in a catch block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, jestjs

I'm testing the code of my react component that checks if all my promises have resolved correctly, and if not, throws an error to be caught by a much higher level error boundary. The code looks as follows, however my test does not pass as it seems to say that my function does **not** throw. Code as as follows:

```
const callA = Promise.resolve();
const callB = Promise.reject();
function doSomething() {
  Promise.all([
    callA,
    callB,
  ]).catch(() => {
    throw new Error('oops');
  })
}

test('do something throws correctly', () => {
  expect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }).toThrow();
});
```

Results in:

```
(node:516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: oops
(node:516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of anasync function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promisewhich was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zeroexit code.
 FAIL  ./sum.test.js
  ✕ do something throws correctly (16ms)

  ● do something throws correctly

    expect(received).toThrow()

    Received function did not throw

      15 |   expect(() => {
      16 |     doSomething();
    > 17 |   }).toThrow();
         |      ^
      18 | });
```

I understand that my error can be resolved if I add a catch to the test after `doSomething()`, however that is not the point of the test. I'm simply attempting to test that doSomething will throw in this scenario, which it seems that it does. How/why does Jest not pass the `expect` of that it should be throwing, and how to fix?

Comment: Your `Promise.all()` will reject, but there's nobody  there to hear it.   Thus, you get the `unhandled rejection` error.  Nobody is listening to the promise that your `Promise.all().catch()` returns.  Thus it is being ignored and the system says you can't ignore a promise that rejects.  I don't know your testing framework to know how it should be written for that.

Comment: Your promise is not awaited when you call it, that's why it does not resolve.  await your promises or use a .catch